# FFmpeg command not working

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to use the command given in the selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679390/ffmpeg-extracting-20-images-from-a-video-of-variable-length), but it does not work when executed. I know that everything else is working since I can create thumbnails with a different command. What is the proper way to format this? I am assuming that the problem is with `" -vsync 0 -vf select='not(mod(n,100))' "` but have not been able to get it working.

```
$cmd = $ffmpeg . " -i " . $src . " -vsync 0 -vf select='not(mod(n,100))' " .  $out . ".jpg";
exec($cmd);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error on this line:

```
$cmd = $ffmpeg . " -i " . $src . " -vsync 0 -vf select='not(mod(n,100))' " .  $out . ".jpg";
```

Change it to:

```
$cmd = "ffmpeg -i " . $src . " -vsync 0 -vf \"select='not(mod(n,100))'\" " .  $out . ".jpg";
```

Or try:

```
$cmd = "ffmpeg -i " . $src . " -vsync 0 -vf select='not(mod(n,100))' " .  $out . ".jpg";
```

Also when you call exec function call it like this:

```
exec($cmd,$out);
print_r($out);
```

Print_r will print you output of what was executed in exec()...