# Get Image from Video

Tags: c#, .net, video-processing, aforge

I am trying to write an application which can access cameras connected to PC, record a video and get an image from the video. I use AForge.NET libraries to access cameras: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/

I don't know how the event named AForge.Video.NewFrameEventHandler works. In this code the event returns null to a bitmap instead of a new frame from a video or the event is not called. I want to get frames from the video to a picture box every time frame to make something like a video stream and after click on the stop button I want the last image to stay displayed in the picture box. Does anyone know how? And why my code doesn't work?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using System.Drawing;
using AForge.Video;

namespace CameraDevice
{
    public class CameraImaging
    {
        // enumerate video devices
        public FilterInfoCollection videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice );
        //camera
        public VideoCaptureDevice videoSource;
        //screen shot
        public Bitmap bitmap;
        public CameraImaging()
        {
            // create video source
            VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[0].MonikerString );
            // set NewFrame event handler
            videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler( video_NewFrame );
        }
        public void StartVideo(VideoCaptureDevice videoSource)
        {
            // start the video source
            videoSource.Start();
            // ...
        }
        public void StopVideo(VideoCaptureDevice videoSource)
        {
            // stop the video source
            videoSource.Stop();
            // ...
        }
        private void video_NewFrame( object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs )
        {
            // get new frame
            bitmap = eventArgs.Frame;
            // process the frame
        }
    }
}
```

The similar code is here: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/directshow_video.html[^]

In the Windows Forms I run this video in a thread which does this method:

```
private void VideoRecording()
    {
        camImg.videoSource.Start();

        while (!StopVideo)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = camImg.bitmap;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
        camImg.videoSource.Stop();

    }
```

Comment: AForge.NET uses native DirectShow API to access video capture hardware. You might want to look at [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) library instead which is the most widely used "bridge" between .NET apps and video capture APIs.

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly the bitmap needs to be copied right away since it is overwritten after the event. Using a reference is no good here. Try something like:

```
private void video_NewFrame( object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs )
{
    // copy the new frame
    bitmap = new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame);
    // process the frame
}
```

or

```
private void video_NewFrame( object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs )
{
   // clone new frame
   bitmap = eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
   // process the frame
}
```

Also you should not use an extra thread for this, AForge already does that.

1. Call Start (e.g. in the load event, or after pressing a button)
2. Handle the frame events

   ```
   private void VideoStream_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
   {
       Bitmap newFrame = new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame);
       pictureBox1.Image = newFrame;
   }
   ```
3. Call Stop (closing event or button)

If you run into issues with WinForm controls e.g. a label you need to know that these controls were created on another thread and you need to use Invoke. E.g:

```
label_ms.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => label_ms.Text = msTimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds.ToString()));
```

Your best bet is to check out this AForge sample that comes with the framework:
http://aforge.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Samples/Video/Player/

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Aforge video library with my Foscams, and it is working very well.
Here is my code for the event handler.

```
private void Video_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //Create Bitmap from frame
        Bitmap FrameData = new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame);
        //Add to PictureBox
        PictureBox.Image = FrameData;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is to [get or write a wrapper around FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163036/solid-ffmpeg-wrapper-for-c-net), which can do the work for you of [extracting images from your video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679390/ffmpeg-extracting-20-images-from-a-video-of-variable-length). I've worked on two projects that have used this means of getting thumbnails and/or stills from uploaded videos. It'll feel a little hackish, but it should work.