# ffmpeg take a screenshot of an flv file every minute

Tags: ffmpeg, screenshot, flv

I'm new to using ffmpeg.  I'd like to take several screenshots of an flv file at 1 minute intervals.

I found this command on ffmpeg's website

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1/60 img%03d.jpg
```

However this does not work, when I run it I get the error 'no such filter 'fps''

Is there an easy way to do this? I am open to using an entirely different program as well, but it has to run on a server from command line.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Runned into same problem, used command line from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679390/ffmpeg-extracting-20-images-from-a-video-of-variable-length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used your command before with success. Perhaps you have an older version of FFmpeg. Please try [**updating**](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) if you have not already.

[**ref**](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)