# ffmpeg capture current frame and overwrite the image output file

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I am trying to extract the image file from a RTSP stream url every second (could be every 1 min also) and overwrite this image file.

my below code works but it outputs to multiple image jpg files: `img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg...`

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://IP_ADDRESS/live.sdp -f image2 -r 1 img%01d.jpg
```

How to use ffmpeg or perhaps bash scripts in Linux to overwrite the same image file while continuously extract the image at a NOT high frequecy, say 1 min or 10 sec?

Comment: there is an "updatefirst" option for image2, IIRC, just remember that if you're on windows, it will be overwriting files as you try to read them, which may cause a conflict/collision

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Following command line should work for you.

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://IP_ADDRESS/live.sdp -f image2 -updatefirst 1 img.jpg
```

Comment: This works for me and I added "-r 1/5" option to make it capture every 5 seconds.

Comment: @pragnesh How would yo do to save each screenshot in a different file?

Comment: it seems `updatefirst` has been removed in ffmpeg version 4.X?

Comment: As pointed out the `-updatefirst` option has been removed and no longer works. Use the `-y` option instead.

Answer (score 22):

To elaborate a bit on the already [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360470/ffmpeg-capture-current-frame-and-overwrite-the-image-output-file/25379282#25379282) from [pragnesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/928492/pragnesh),

### FFmpeg

As stated in the [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis):
ffmpeg command line options are specified as

*ffmpeg [global_options] {[input_options] -i input_file} ... {[output_options] output_file} ...*

So

`ffmpeg -i rtsp://<rtsp_source_addr> -f image2 -update 1 img.jpg`

Uses [output option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) -f image2 , force output format to image2 format, as part of the muxer stage.

- Note that in ffmpeg, if the output file name specifies an image format the image2 muxer will be used by default, so the command could be shortened to:

  `ffmpeg -i rtsp://<rtsp_source_addr> -update 1 img.jpg`

The [image2 format muxer](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2) expects a filename pattern, such as `img%01d.jpg` to produce a sequentially numbered series of files. If the [**update** option](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-3) is set to 1, the filename will be interpreted as just a filename, not a pattern, thereby overwriting the same file.

Using the **-r** , set frame rate, [video option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options) works, but generated me a whole lot of dropping frame messages which was bugging me.

Thanks to [another answer on the same topic](https://superuser.com/questions/663928/ffmpeg-to-capture-stills-from-h-264-stream/664601#664601), I found the [fps Video Filter](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps-1) to do a better job.

So my version of the working command is

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://<rtsp_source_addr> -vf fps=fps=1/20 -update 1 img.jpg
```

For some reason still unkown to me the minimum framerate I can achieve from my feed is 1/20 or 0.05.

There also exists the video filter thumbnail, which selects an image from a series of frames but this is more processing intensive and therefore I would not recommend it.

Most of this and more I found on the [FFMpeg Online Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)

### AVconv

For those of you who use avconv it is very similar. They are after all forks of what was once a common library. The [AVconv image2 documentation is found here](https://libav.org/avconv.html#image2-2).

`avconv -i rtsp://<rtsp_source_addr> -vf fps=fps=1/20 -update 1 img.jpg`

As Xianlin pointed out there may be a couple other interesting options to use:

**-an** : Disables audio recording.

- Found in [Audio Options Section](https://libav.org/avconv.html#Audio-Options)

**-r** *< fps >* : sets frame rate

- Found in the [Video Options Section](https://libav.org/avconv.html#Video-Options)
- used as an output option is actually a a substitute for the [fps filter](https://libav.org/avconv.html#fps-1)

leading to an alternate version :

`avconv -i rtsp://<rtsp_source_addr> -r 1/20 -an -update 1 img.jpg`

Hope it helps understand for possible further tweaking ;)

Comment: to use avconv instead of ffmpeg,  `avconv -i rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov -r 1/20 -an -y -update 1 test.jpg`

Comment: According to the **-r** [Video Options docs](https://libav.org/avconv.html#Video-Options), **-r** option actually causes the fps filter to be inserted. so **-vf fps=fps=1/20** should also do the same. But it is shorter with -r :) Also I don't think you need the **-y** *(
Overwrite output files without asking)* option as the **-update 1** already knows it should overwrite. **-an** addition is an interesting one, which may reduce process guessing. Thanks for the comment I'll update the answer with avconv option.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get the option -update working to overwrite the .jpg. Doing some experiments resulted in a working solution (at least for me) with the option -y at the end (upper-case is not working). I also needed http:// instead of rstp:// for this camera.

`ffmpeg -i http://xx:yy@192.168.1.xx:yyy/snapshot.cgi /tmp/Capture2.jpg -y`

Answer (score 0):

Grab a snapshot from an RTSP video stream every 10 seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash
#fetch-snapshots.sh
url='rtsp://IP_ADDRESS/live.sdp'
avconv -i $url -r 0.1 -vsync 1 -qscale 1 -f image2 images%09d.jpg
```

-r rate  set frame rate to 0.1 frames a second (this equals to 1 frame every 10 seconds).
Thanks to westonruter, see https://gist.github.com/westonruter/4508842

Furthermore have a look at [FFMPEG: Extracting 20 images from a video of variable length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679390/ffmpeg-extracting-20-images-from-a-video-of-variable-length)

Comment: so I will have 6 images within 60 seconds, how about I only have ONLY one image overwritten 6 times within 60 seconds? That's what I need.

Comment: Have you tried the option ‘-y (global)’
Overwrite output files without asking.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg -i rtsp://root:password@192.168.1.1/mpeg4 -ss 00:00:01 -f image2 -vframes 1 thumb.jpg

- replace with your rtsp protocol url
- make sure 00:00:01
- if you put other numbers, the image will be crashed