# Swift - How to get current frame of a m3u8 live stream?

Tags: swift, video-streaming, m3u8

I would like to get an `UIImage` of the current image/frame of a m3u8 live stream.

I saw of lot of code on forums, ... but they only work for video but not for streams

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ffmpag](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)  to get frames from live stream video

Mobile framework [mobile-ffmpeg](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg)

command :

```
ffmpeg -i https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4 -f image2 -r 1 img%01d.jpg
```

for more information read [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360470/ffmpeg-capture-current-frame-and-overwrite-the-image-output-file)

Comment: I only mention it in the title, but the code I'm looking for is in Swift not in command :/

Comment: you can use this command in swift code :)  check this lib https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg

Comment: Oh sorry, actually I just understand why the url of mobile-ffmpeg didn't work, and I just see it's possible in Swift :/ Thanks :D